# tex.sprint in LuaLaTeX

Tags: automation, lua, luacode

I would like to print text as per `XML` file. But when using `tex.sprint` enter mark is removed and all the text are displayed in single line in PDF. How do avoid this?

My `ds.tex` file is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}

local foo = require "lua/ds"
foo.flowDom("ds.xml")

\end{luacode*}

\end{document}
```

My `ds.xml` file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
</Root>
```

my `ds.lua` file is:

```
local function flowDom(xml)
    local function readfile(filename)
       local f = assert(io.open(filename, 'r'))
       local t = f:read('*all')
       f:close()
       return t
    end
    local json = utilities.json
    local domobject = require "luaxml-domobject"
    XMLIn = readfile(xml)
    local dom = domobject.parse(XMLIn)
        tex.sprint(XMLIn)
end
return { flowDom = flowDom }
```

In Command/Terminal prompt i have used:

`lualatex ds.tex`.

Comment: According to the [wiki](http://wiki.luatex.org/index.php/Writing_Lua_in_TeX) `tex.sprint` doesn't add end-of-line characters, maybe try `tex.print` instead

Comment: @DG': I have tried `tex.print` and result is the same (enter marks are removed in the PDF)

Comment: Do you want to print the code *as* code? wrap it in a `listings` environment

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate what your ultimate goal is. Do you simply want to pretty print an XML file or do you want to process the contents of the XML futher?

Comment: @DG': I must need as perl XML structure (like <Root> enter and <p>Hello World!</p> enter like that). So my ultimate goal is need to print each element with enter mark.

Comment: I don't know what that means and it doesn't answer my question. Also, what is a *enter mark*? Do you mean a newline (like `\n`)? Again: If you want to simply print the contents of the xml file, you don't need to parse it. If you want to process the elements, tell us how.

Comment: @DG': Yes i mean newline only and just want to print the contents of the XML file only. No need to parse also. No need to process the elements also. I have need as per XML with new line.

Comment: @Balaji this is identical to your question I answered yesterday except that your input is xml not tex, but since you are not parsing the files it does not make any difference what the format is.  you don't need Lua in either case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to print a XML file in your document, you don't need to parse it, you can use `\lstinputlisting`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[language=XML]{ds.xml}

\end{document}
```

[image]